# Firebase "no such instance field" error

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, instance

As the title says, I have encountered that error when I tried working with Firebase database. I have tried numerous solutions found online but nothing seems to have worked for me. Below you can find my code and also, a brief information regarding on what I've tried so far before posting on stackOverflow.

The code is the following:

```
package com.example.vlad.restaurantorder;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.vlad.restaurantorder.Model.User;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editPhone, editPassword;
    Button btnLogIn;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference tableUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

    btnLogIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogInScreenLogIn);
    editPhone = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
    editPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

    //database
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    tableUser = database.getReference("User");

    btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LogIn.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progressDialog.show();

            tableUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot.child(editPhone.getText().toString()).exists()){
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        User user = dataSnapshot.child(editPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                        if(user.getPassword().equals(editPassword.getText().toString())){

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log in failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User does not exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });


}
```

}

What I have tried so far before posting here: Disabling proGuard and putting minifyEnable on false in build.gradle in debug{}; Restarting android studio, as I've read other people's posts who also encountered the problem said that this worked for them; On line where I used `tableUser = database.getReference("User");` I also tried using `tableUser = database.getReference().child("User");`

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you very much

Later edit: adding the LogIn activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/login_screen_image"
tools:context="com.example.vlad.restaurantorder.LogIn">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPhone"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:text="0293292442"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
        app:met_maxCharacters="11"
        app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
        app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
        />

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:text="5678"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
        app:met_maxCharacters="11"
        app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
        app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
    android:id="@+id/btnLogInScreenLogIn"
    android:text="@string/LogIn"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:buttonColor="@color/btnLogIn"
    app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
    app:shadowEnabled="true"
    app:shadowHeight="5dp"
    app:cornerRadius="4dp"
    />
```

Later edit: LogCat image:

[image]

Comment: If you ignore the "no such instance field" message from the debugger, is your code working?  Any exceptions?

Comment: I can't be sure if it'll work, since I don't know what happens afterwards. The problem is that in     "btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {" won't even enter inside this function (I've tried debugging) and gives me the "no such instance field"

Comment: Can you add Logcat please.

Comment: You mean LogIn activity xml? What I've posted is the LogIn class.

Comment: No Logcat is where you see the errors. It is in left bottom at Android Studio

Comment: Ooh, ok. I'll add a screenshot then when I'll get home from work.

Comment: @FurkanOyken I have added the LogCat image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code should work just fine if there is no other warning/error showing up. The missing instance error/message might only be because it takes some time to read the data from Firebase.

After adding the `ValueEventListener`, the app will take some time to "listen" to or read the data from Firebase. So, add some log messages to each of the `if/else` block as below, recompile and fire up the app, open the Logcat view in Android Studio and then click the button `btnLogIn` on the app screen. Then wait (make sure internet is available to the device/emulator and Firebase Database is connected).

In Logcat window, you should see the Log messages show up depending on the `if/else` block that was entered in onDataChange. E.g..... `D/ANY_TAG: entered onDataChange`

Code with debug lines:

```
tableUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Log.d("ANY_TAG", "entered onDataChange");
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(editPhone.getText().toString()).exists()){

                        Log.d("ANY_TAG", "entered onDataChange/childExists");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        User user = dataSnapshot.child(editPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                        if(user.getPassword().equals(editPassword.getText().toString())){

                            Log.d("ANY_TAG", "entered onDataChange/childExists/equalPassword");    
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.d("ANY_TAG", "entered onDataChange/childExists/unEqualPasswords");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log in failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("ANY_TAG", "entered onDataChange/childDoesNotExist");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User does not exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}
```